# Выборка из двух таблиц с учётом иных связей?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Есть вот такая БД
[image: Схема БД]

Как написать запрос, чтобы на выдачу получить такие колонки:
`Grands_Prix.Round`,
`Grands_Prix.Title`,
`Grands_Prix.Country`,
`Grands_Prix_Racers.Position`,
`Racers.Name`,
`Teams.Title`, если мне нужно, чтобы выдача была исключительно по одной команде?

Это или `Teams.Title`, или `Teams.id` (или `Racers_Teams_Seasons.Teams_Id`?) Я пытаюсь через `Teams.id`.

Вот такой запрос выдаёт очень странный результат: выводит каждую гонку любого гонщика, при этом выдаёт разные позиции на одну и ту же гонку, но всем исправно пишет одну и ту же команду, что неправда.

```
SELECT Grands_Prix.Round,
    Grands_Prix.Title,
    Grands_Prix.Country,
    Grands_Prix_Racers.Position,
    Racers.Name,
    Teams.Title,
    Teams.Id
FROM Grands_Prix, Grands_Prix_Racers, Racers, Teams
WHERE Teams.id = 6
```

На скрине ответа на запрос это не видно, но обратите внимание, что строк в ответе 693 120.

Всего в команде 2 гонщика, 38 гонок, значит, результатов по логике должно быть 76.

[image: Ответ на запрос]

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Comment: В целом, в операторе SQL отсутствуют JOINS между таблицами. Вот почему результат неверный.

Comment: Да, спасибо, на джойны уже направили, посмотрел, написал свой вариант, всё работает. Что касается минимального воспроизводимого примера — прошу прощения, думал этого достаточно для умозрительного понимания, не подумал про то, что это кто-то может запустить на своей машине)

Answer (score 0):

В конечном итоге я запрос создал таким и он работает. Прошу прощения за глупые комменты, писал сам для себя.

```
SELECT
  -- Берём Раунд (какое Гран-При по счёту), Автодром, Страну и Где автодром находится, Гонщика, \
  -- его Финальную позицию и Команду
  E.Round, E.Circuit, E.Country, E.Location, F.Name, F.Position, F.Title 
FROM 
  Grands_Prix as E -- ЭТО ТАБЛИЦА Е!
-- Джойним (справа, по id Гран-При) таблицу Гран-при и F
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
  (
  SELECT
    -- Берём id гонки (Гран-При), позицию пилота на финише, его имя и название команды
    C.Grands_Prix_Id, C.Position, D.Name, D.Title 
  -- Джойним (справа, по id пилотов) таблицу связи Гран-При--пилотов \
  -- с таблицей А (см. то, что в RIGHT OUTER JOIN)
  FROM
    Grands_Prix_Racers as C -- ЭТО ТАБЛИЦА С!
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    (
      SELECT 
        -- Берём id пилота, его имя и название команды
        A.Id, A.Name, B.Title 
      FROM 
        (
        SELECT  
          -- Берём id пилота, его имя, id команды, сезон 
          Racers.Id, Racers.Name, Racers_Teams_Seasons.Teams_Id, Racers_Teams_Seasons.Seasons_Year 
        -- Джойним (справа, по id команд) таблицы гонщиков и таблицу связей гонщиков-коман-сезонов 
        FROM 
          Racers
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
          Racers_Teams_Seasons
        ON 
          Racers.Id = Racers_Teams_Seasons.Racer_Id
        WHERE
          -- по условию, сезон — 2020, Команда по id — 3 (Racing Point)
          (Seasons_Year = 2020) AND (Teams_Id = 3) 
        ) as A -- В СКОБКАХ — ЭТО ТАБЛИЦА А!

      LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Teams as B -- ЭТО ТАБЛИЦА В!
      ON
        A.Teams_Id = B.Id 
    ) as D -- ЭТО ТАБЛИЦА D!
  ON
    C.Racers_Id = D.Id
  WHERE
    -- Берём Гран-При с id выше 21 \
    -- В 2019 году было 21 Гран-При, следовательно, \
    -- так берём все ГП 2020 года 
    -- [Я знаю, это косяк архитектуры. \
    -- На будущее — перестать запрещать изменения в любых таблицах!])
    C.Grands_Prix_Id > 21  
                 
  ) as F -- ЭТО ТАБЛИЦА F!
ON
  E.Id = F.Grands_Prix_Id
```

Comment: Первый раз вижу любителя right join . Не удивительно что у вас проблемы с запросами.